# HTML5 IE 9 .mov

Tags: html5-video

I have a problem about html5 video playing on IE 9

I'm using .mov to play the video.

Some of videos play but some is not play.

Example:

I clicked video1.mov and it play.
I clicked video2.mov and it is not play.

Is there a problem about the codec of the video?

What should I do?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Check this image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXwCK.png

Left Side Image - That video is play.

Right Side Image - That video is not play.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive with your question?
What videos (in particular) aren't working?
Is there any way you can show us precisely what trouble you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it is because of the codec. I think it requires video encoding with the H.264 codec and audio encoding with the ACC codec.

Did you download these files separately or encoded them massively together?

If you downloaded them separately, it may because of different encoding codecs.

Comment: if you are using Windows 7, right click on the video file and choose MediaInfo, there should be enough information. Or use some codec tools.

Comment: Look at this

http://i.stack.imgur.com/iXwCK.png

Left Side Image - That video is play.

Right Side Image - That video is not play.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not professional in this field, just try to help :) But there's some different from both of them, not the encode, but Data Rate seems to be the problem. Sometimes video files with high bitrate/datarate are difficult to play with.

Comment: But when I direct to the link where the video is it play. like this http://www.workercoach.com/1_M1_S1_SC40_1.mov

Comment: When I click to your link, it will play the file by local audio player (QuickTime in my case) but if you use HTML5, it will use the built-in player function (of IE in your case). It could make them different.

Comment: I think this is out of my knowledge now, sorry :(

Comment: I figured out how to run it. Thanks to your help :)